# How to send all windows traffic over a SOCKS 5 proxy?

Tags: firefox, ssh, proxy, putty

I have a socks5 proxy set up using a putty ssh tunnel. I can use it fine when I change the proxy settings in firefox. I also need other programs that don't support a proxy configuration to use the SOCKS5 proxy.

Are there any good programs that will route all my traffic from all my windows 8.1 programs through the proxy?

I tried to use FreeCap but that doesn't work so well and you have to manually add all programs to it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a program called Widecap that does exactly what I need.